# printDialog.PrinterSettings.IsValid returns true always

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to check if my defaultprinter is on, In case it is not on, I want to select another printer. I use the below code to check if it is on, but it returns true always.
any help would be appreciated

```
bool printerIsOnline = false;
printerIsOnline = printDialog.PrinterSettings.IsValid;
```

Comment: I change the code of the answer, please test it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to Check if printer is default, you can use `PrintDialog` as follow:

```
printDialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "MyDefaultPrinterName";
bool printerIsOnline = false;
printerIsOnline = printDialog.PrinterSettings.IsDefaultPrinter;
```

If you want to Check if printer is on (Connected), you can use `WMI class` like this :

1- Add the reference `System.Management.dll` to your Project.

2- Using the Reference in your code :

```
using System.Management;
```

3-Use this code to check if printer is online (connected) :

```
bool printerIsOnline = true;
string printerName = "MyPrinterName";
string query = string.Format("SELECT * from Win32_Printer WHERE Name LIKE '%{0}'", printerName);
ManagementObjectSearcher searcherPrinters = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
foreach (ManagementObject printer in searcherPrinters.Get())
{
    printerIsOnline = !printer["WorkOffline"].ToString().Equals("True");
}
```

With this code you access to many properties of printer :

[All the properties of the printer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394363.aspx)

Comment: I have the name of my default printer, but when the default printer is off the printing text goes to the queue, what i want is to check if it is off then select another printer.